# How do I store value from a register to absolute Address using ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I want to store a register value to an address using ARM assembly. I am looking for something like this,

```
STR R0, =0x20000000            // store r0 to 0x20000000
```

But this is an error ofcourse.

One way to do this is as follows,

```
LDR R1, =0x20000000
STR R0, [R1 + #0]
```

But I want to do it using only one register, as mentioned above. So is there any way to do that?

Comment: There is not enough place in the machine code to encode a full 32 bit absolute address, so no. You could of course save a register to the stack if you don't have a free one to use.

Comment: What is the size of machine code instruction?

Comment: @MuzahirHussain In thumb code (as used on the Cortex M3), instructions are 2 or 4 bytes long.

Comment: this is risc not cisc...you generally need a register for the address and one for the value.  if doing a read then you can often do that with one register.

Comment: No single instruction exists which can do this. What is the context / requirement for this? If inline in 'C' you can just use 'C' casting to do what you want. If in a separate assembler function you can usually use the stack, perhaps in conjunction with LR; or with some versions of the ABI it might be permissible to trash R12 (IP).

Comment: Simple answer, no. You need two registers on a Cortex-M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want to do it using only one register, as mentioned above.

There is no instuction available that lets you do that, all store instructions require at least one register for the destionation address.

The reason is quite simple: Despite having 32-bit instructions there are not enough bits available in those to encode a full 32-bit address, as you always need some more bits for the opcode.

The optinal offset in the load and store instructions are limited for the same reason.